# How can solve $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin\pi x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{1-x^2}{\sin\ (π x)}$$

---

How can i solve this limit.

Comment: Write $\sin\pi x=\sin(\pi-\pi x)$ and use $1-x=t$.

Comment: Have you tried L'Hopital's rule?https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_l%27Hôpital

Comment: @terrace: in Spanish, and likely in other latin languages, the modern form of the word is "seno", and it is denoted mathematically by "sen". Not everybody is as proficient in English as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you have $1-x^2=(1+x)(1-x)$, so the only part you care about is 
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x}{\sin\pi x}.
$$
If you make the change of variable $t=1-x$, you get
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\sin\pi(1-t)}.
$$
Now, $$\sin\pi(1-t)=\sin(\pi-\pi t)=\sin\pi t.$$
Putting everything together, 
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin\pi x}
=2\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x}{\sin\pi x}
=2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\sin\pi t}
=\frac2\pi\,\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\pi t}{ \sin\pi t}
=\frac2\pi.
$$

---

The non-funny way is to use L'Hôpital, to get 
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin\pi x}
=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{-2x}{\pi\cos\pi x}
=\frac{-2}{-\pi}=\frac2\pi.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Have you learned l'hopital rule? if so you have

$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1-x^2}{\sin(\pi x)} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{-2x}{\pi \cos (\pi x)} = \frac{-2}{-\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}$